# How force parent div to stretch horizontally to accommodate floated child divs?

Tags: html, css

I want the blue div (as shown in the fiddle below) to be to the right of the red div. Instead it's below. If I set parent to `overflow: hidden`, it's still below and just hides it.

**EDIT: In simplifying my code, I left out the `display: table` on my text div. I have added that in here:** http://jsfiddle.net/z1385n05/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/z1385n05/

http://jsfiddle.net/z1385n05/1/ (with `overflow: hidden`)

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1">1</div>
        <div class="child2"><span>Child 2 is longer than the edge, I don't want it to wrap</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer
{
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
    border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

.parent
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.child1
{
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.child2
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
}

.child span
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your updated question you can achieve this if you set parent `display:table` and `.child2` `display:table-cell`

```
.parent
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:table;/*Add this*/
}

.child2
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;/*Add this*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z1385n05/6/)

Comment: Odd, that works with that example (which I simplified) but my actual code uses `display: table` on the text div (sorry not in original code) and it doesn't work with that: http://jsfiddle.net/z1385n05/3/

Comment: I didn't include it to simplify the code. Sorry. I can't remove the display table because I need to align the text at the bottom.

Comment: I solved it with your help and making the parent `display: table` and the text div `display: table-cell`. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your anser to be what's in that fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the blue box is floating below the red box is because there is not enough horizontal space for them to be side by side.

To solve this there are 2 solutions:

1) increase the width of .outer until the boxes are side by side

For example:

```
.outer
{
    position: relative;
    width: 620px;
    height: 480px;
    border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
```

Or

2) increase the width of .parent until the boxes are side by side

For example:

```
.parent
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 620px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer div is too small to accomodate text without wrapping.

Try this, increase width, tested on jsfiddle you posted:

```
.outer
{
    position: relative;
    width: 620px;
    height: 480px;
    border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
```

Cheers !!

Comment: I can't increase the width. It has to be that narrow.

Comment: Please see @Alek's answer above